# дискорд бот, NoneType

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Суть бота заключается в том что когда я нажимаю на реакцию под сообщением у меня должна выдаваться роль если я нажму еще раз на реакцию - забираться так вот. У меня была ошибка с `AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'")`, её я пофиксил методом добавления параметра из функции payload `member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id=payload.user_id)` на этот `member = payload.member` ладно, это пофиксили идем дальше, ошибка - `AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'")` проделал такие же махинации с этой функцией (они почти одинаковые) но ошибка так и осталась, не понимаю почему, проверил все print вроде все принимает, но в чем проблема я не знаю, но мне кажется что я упустил что-то очевидное, раскройте мне глаза пожалуйста. Вот код:
`

```
import discord
from discord import utils
import time
import config


class MyClient(discord.Client):
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    global emoji
    global member
    if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
        member = payload.member
        print(member)
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

            if (len([i for i in payload.member.roles if i and i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= 1):

                await payload.member.add_roles(role)
                print(time.asctime())
                print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))

        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    global member
    global emoji
    channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
    print(member)
    try:
        emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
        role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
        await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
        print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))

    except KeyError as e:
        print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)`
```

Comment: Гуглите что за ошибка. У вас что там происходит хакатон по телеграм ботам и дискордку?

Comment: Я гуглил, там очень мало информации об этой проблемы, а даже если я и находил там не то что мне нужно, я не просто так обратился сюда

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87_3zcv8q5I 

Comment: Да, но оно не работает, у меня ошибка с NoneType я пытался сам фиксить но у меня не выходило